# Filter function that supports more fields at the same time

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this function that filters through elements. For example if I have this array:

```
arr = [{'name': 'a', 'group': 'aa'}, {'name': 'b', 'group': 'bb'}, {'name': 'c', 'group': 'cc'}, {'name': 'a', 'group': 'dd'}]
```

And I filter it by `'name=a'`, it will return me

```
{'name': 'a', 'group': 'aa'}
{'name': 'a', 'group': 'dd'}
```

But how can I put another condition, not just on `name`. For example I want to search after `name=a` and `group=aa` and return:

```
{'name': 'a', 'group': 'aa'}
```

This is my function but it only receives one field at the moment

```
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
      return items;
    }

    this.newArray = items.filter(singleItem => {
      return (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && value.indexOf(singleItem[field]) >= 0);
    });

    return this.newArray
  }
```

How can I modify it (doing something like `value` which is a `string[]`)? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What would `field` be set to in your example, and what would `value` be set to?

Comment: `{name: 'a', group: 'aa'}` I am sorry, this is what it will be set @user184994. So field `name` and `group` AND value `a` and `aa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for the wanted filters

> ```
> {
>     name: 'a',
>     group: 'aa'
> }
> ```

and iterate this key/value by checking it with the object's values.

This approach accepts an arbitrary count of properties.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'a', group: 'aa' }, { name: 'b', group: 'bb' }, { name: 'c', group: 'cc' }, { name: 'a', group: 'dd' }],
    filter = { name: 'a', group: 'aa' },
    result = array.filter(o => Object.entries(filter).every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can I build that `filter` array if  the reason why I am doing this filter function is to find the value of `filter`?

Comment: `filter` is an object and you coud just use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for it.

Comment: I am sorry, I just realized what a mistake I said. You are right, I will check this right now.

Comment: I have a question, what if `a` is assigned to more groups, and I want filter to be something like this: `filter = { name: 'a', group: 'aa', group: 'gg' }`. I can't duplicate `group`. Can you help me, @NinaScholz?

Comment: you could take an array and check with `.every(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(v) ? v.includes(o[k]) : o[k] === v))`

Comment: An array containing what? `['a', 'aa', 'gg']`? Im sorry for asking that many questions!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183194/discussion-between-tenzolinho-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.newArray = items.filter(
  singleItem => singleItem && singleItem.name === 'a' && singleItem.group === 'aa'
);
```